# Comparing DateTime with SqlDateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, datetime, exception

When I compare a DateTime variable with SqlDateTime.MinValue:

```
if (StartDate > SqlDateTime.MinValue)
{
  // some code
}
```

I get the following runtime exception if StartDate is < SqlDateTime.MinValue:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and
>   12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

This can be easy solved with a small change:

```
if (StartDate > SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value)
{
  // some code
}
```

I understand that in the first code snippet I'm comparing apples to oranges. What I don't understand is the exception message. It seems like I'm assigning a DateTime value to a SqlDateTime variable.

What am I missing?

Comment: I forgot to state that that happened when StartDate was lower than SqlDateTime.MinValue

Comment: The compiler looks for a way to compare two completely different classes.  The only way it can do it is by using the [operator overload](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDateTime.cs,514) that SqlDateTime provides.  But that requires it to convert the DateTime to a SqlDateTime.   And that throws.  The alternative you found uses the operator overload that DateTime provides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET native DateTime type (to be specific, its a structure) holds a broader range of possible values than the SqlDateTime data type can support. More specifically, a DateTime value can range from 01/01/0000 to a theoretical 12/31/9999.

When the compiler tries to coerce the types for comparison, it attempts to put a DateTime value (MinValue.Value) that's outside (below or 'before' in context)  the range supported by SqlDateTime - hence the overflow.

Comment: Why should it try to coerce the first operand into the second one and not the other way around?

Comment: I believe the compiler interprets the comparison operator as an operator defined by the SqlDataType, and thus attempts to convert the compared element to a SqlDateTime via implicit conversion.

Comment: I thought perhaps @Gnomo's question deserved a better response than I offered. In particular, the overflow happens because C#'s *scope resolution* mechanism chose the overload for the "less-than" operator `<` associated with that in the 'closest' class - 'SqlDateTime' - and the parameters for that overload are, naturally, two SqlDateTime objects. C# then notices the implicit conversion from a DateTime to SqlDateTime, and tries to assign the provided value, which then overflows. See Eric Lippert's great commentary on 'closeness' at https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/

Answer (score 0):

From [SqlDateTime Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime) on MSDN:

> **SqlDateTime  structure**
>
> Represents the date and time data ranging in value from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999 to an accuracy of 3.33 milliseconds to be stored in or retrieved from a database. The SqlDateTime structure has a different underlying data structure from its corresponding .NET Framework type, DateTime, which can represent any time between 12:00:00 AM 1/1/0001 and 11:59:59 PM 12/31/9999, to the accuracy of 100 nanoseconds. SqlDateTime actually stores the relative difference to 00:00:00 AM 1/1/1900. Therefore, a conversion from "00:00:00 AM 1/1/1900" to an integer will return 0.